# Signature verification for InCommon SAML metadata using xmlsec1 fails

Tags: openssl, xml, saml

[InCommon Federation](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/InCommon+Federation) provides IdP and SP metadata. Their refresh policy recommends frequent checking of the [metadata aggregate](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/Metadata+Aggregates) to use the most recent version. They strongly recommend InCommon SPs [refresh and verify metadata](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/Metadata+Consumption) at least daily.

Following instruction provided on [Metadata Consumption](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/Metadata+Consumption) page, I download an aggregate and obtain an authentic copy of the Metadata Signing Certificate.

Then, I'm to "Verify the XML signature on downloaded metadata." This is where I'm having issues. I'm able to verify the downloaded metadata *with the embedded x509 certificate*, but cannot verify using the separately downloaded Metadata Signing Certificate.

I have the two files downloaded from InCommon:

- xml: `InCommon-metadata-idp-only.xml`
- private signing key: `inc-md-cert.pem`

I thought I should be able to run the command:

```
# xmlsec1 --verify \
     --id-attr:ID urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata:EntitiesDescriptor \
     --privkey-pem ./inc-md-cert.pem \
     ./InCommon-metadata-idp-only.xml
```

That fails saying "Failed to load private key from ./inc-md-cert.pem". I can verify it contains a valid key using `openssl x509 -text -in ./inc-md-cert.pem`. ( and it's readable, and that's the correct path.) Fails the same way if I reference it with `--privkey-pem` or `--pubkey-pem`.

Now, if I use `--pubkey-cert-pem ./inc-md-cert.pem` instead, it runs without error, indicating `OK SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1`.

But no, it's clearly ignoring my private signing key, and simply doing verification based on the key embedded in the metadata.xml file. (I can remove the `--pubkey-cert-pem` argument completely, and the verify still works, using the embedded x509 certificate.

### Update

Given that the provided signature file is self-signed (by the organization) I tried adding itself as a trusted certificate.  For example if you try basic verify with openssl, compare:

```
# openssl verify ./inc-md-cert.pem
error 18 at 9 depth lookup:self signed certificate
# openssl verify -CAfile ./inc-md-cert.pem ./inc-md-cert.pem
./inc-md-cert.pem: OK
```

So what if that's the problem? So I try adding the `--trusted-pem` option

```
# xmlsec1 --verify \
     --id-attr:ID urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata:EntitiesDescriptor \
     --privkey-pem ./inc-md-cert.pem \
     --trusted-pem ./inc-md-cert.pem \
     ./InCommon-metadata-idp-only.xml
func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoadBIO:file=app.c:line=263:
   obj=unknown:subj=PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey and PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY:
   error=4:crypto library function failed: 
func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoad:file=app.c:line=153:
   obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoadBIO:
   error=1:xmlsec library function failed:
   filename=/tmp/inc-md-cert.pem;errno=2
func=xmlSecAppCryptoSimpleKeysMngrKeyAndCertsLoad:file=crypto.c:line=118:
   obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad:
   error=1:xmlsec library function failed:uri=./inc-md-cert.pem
Error: failed to load public key from "./inc-md-cert.pem".
Error: keys manager creation failed
```

Fundamental error on my part, I assume, as this can't be so difficult: How do I use an external key  (provided by InCommon) to verify the signature of the metadata file (provided by InCommon)?

Comment: I see this in xmlsec1 manual: `--print-debug` and `--print-xml-debug` but also for `--id-attr` it says: *this is a hack and if you can use DTD or schema to declare ID attributes instead* (so this may have consequences). Do you have the associate certificate file and did you try to provide it after `--privkey-pem` private key? Try `strace` on the process to see what it does with this private key file to finish with "Failed to load". Also current versions for XML Signature & co are at 2.0 and xmlsec**1** may not be able to deal with them...

Comment: --print-debug appears to simply move debug output from stderr to stdout. The --id-attr seems to do what it's supposed to do, as it successfully find the ID within the XML file. `strace` shows the failure after reading my provided `inc-md-cert.pem` file (I've added more error messages above.) I wonder if it's due to self-signed certificate, without being able to find a valid CA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, though it feels a bit unsatisfying:

a) Verify the InCommon metadata file **using the embedded certificate**.

```
# xmlsec1  --verify --id-attr:ID \ 
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata:EntitiesDescriptor  \
       ./InCommon-metadata-idp-only.xml
OK
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
```

b) Then, simply compare the embedded certificate with the separately downloaded certificate -- they should match, modulo white space. Note that one or the other certificates may be chained, which you should ignore for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of struggle, I found out you can try adding `--enabled-key-data` to your command line, for example:

`--enabled-key-data rsa`
or 
`--enabled-key-data x509`

Either those should work. You can also try

`xmlsec1 --list-key-data` to see the ones you can choose.

In your case it seems that

```
xmlsec1 --verify \
  --enabled-key-data rsa \
  --id-attr:ID urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata:EntitiesDescriptor \
  --pubkey-cert-pem ./inc-md-cert.pem \
  ./InCommon-metadata-idp-only.xml
```

should do what you want.